# Wifi detection is low with AR9485 adaptor on 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu Bionic.

Somehow Ubuntu can't detect or display low bar signals to a Wi-Fi that shows 2 bar on my Android, I even tried a Windows machine and it displayed  3 up to 4 bar signals.

Is there a way to solve this? Why Ubuntu 18.04 (or the one I have at least) can't detect close ranged Wi-Fi?

I have run the network diagnostics; [here is the output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r8Ys4xHx5t/)

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [103c:1785]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: did you try `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: The results are almost same to what I see on the wifi tab!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. Here are the information you've asked : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r8Ys4xHx5t/